# Display an image with tkinter and Pillow

Tags: tkinter, pycharm, python-imaging-library, ubuntu-18.04, opencv, python

Here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk

window = tk .Tk()

img = cv2.imread('bee1.jpg')

height, width, no_channels = img.shape

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = width, height = height)
canvas.pack()

photo = PIL.ImageTk(0,0,image=photo,anchor=tk.NW)


window.mainloop()
```

I am running in Pycharm 2019.3, Ubuntu (latest)

I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

The image I am trying to load is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eUhf.jpg)

Comment: Have you done any research on this? When I search for the error message on Google I get lots of results.

Comment: I have tried every possible way to fix this with no success,

Comment: btw, tried tkinter, cv2, PIL, Pillow, Imageio modules and all come up with the same error.  I have a feeling it has to do with my environment.  I also tried PIP install of all the modules and even loaded them in the Pycharm interpreter

Comment: If you've tried every possible way, it would be good to add that as part of your question so people don't try to recommend things you've already tried. Also, if you think it might be due to your environment, please include details about your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things going wrong in your code:

- you need to import PIL with `from PIL import Image` else you will get the errors you are seeing,
- you shouldn't really use OpenCV to read images here for 2 reasons... firstly it all uses PIL underneath anyway so you are adding a unnecessary dependency and secondly because OpenCV works with BGR order rather than RGB so everything is back-to-front unless you change it, which means you may as well use PIL to read images in the first place.

---

Anyway, enough smugness from me, here's some working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()

img = Image.open('bee.jpg')
width, height = img.size

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width = width, height = height)
canvas.pack()

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
canvas.create_image(width//2, height//2, image=photo)

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!  This actually worked!  First time ever I am able to display an image with PyCharm!  Thank you very much